# LAMBDA Troubles

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, lambda

Why is this not working?

I feel like I am losing my mind.

I am using asp.net core with entity frameworks. This code in my controller is not working. I just want to return the ChildLans where the ParentOrgLevel contains 0001 at the beginning.

Model

```
public class CORP_MatrixPositionOLDWay
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ParentLAN { get; set; }

    public string ChildLAN { get; set; }
    public string ChildOrgLevel { get; set; }

    public string ParentOrgLevel { get; set; }

}
```

View

```
model IEnumerable<Certifications.Models.CORP_MatrixPositionOLDWay>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>

                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ParentOrgLevel)
                </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ParentOrgLevel)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()

        {
            var ParentORG = _context.CORP_MatrixPositionOLDWay
                 .Where(i => i.ParentLAN == UserInformation.Globals.LANID)
                 .Select(i => i.ParentOrgLevel);


            return View(ParentORG);
        }
```

UserInformation.Globals.LANID is a string variable for the machines LANID

Comment: Define "not working"?  Do you get an error?  Do you get unexpected results and if so how do they differ from what you want?

Comment: it keeps saying cant convert from bool to system.func<char,bool>

Comment: i.ParentOrgLevel.StartsWith("0001")  this portion of the code has the error.

Comment: I think we need to see your entities to determine what you need, but basically you're passing the wrong thing to `Where`.

Comment: @CaseyGore my answer should fix your problem

Comment: all of my entities are public strings

Comment: Your entities are public strings?  Do you mean your properties?  It is really hard to help you when we have no idea what the class looks like.

Comment: public class CORP_MatrixPositionOLDWay


    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string ParentLAN { get; set; }

        public string ChildLAN { get; set; }
        public string ChildOrgLevel { get; set; }

        public string ParentOrgLevel { get; set; }

    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         This is my model

Comment: The code is relevant to your question.  Edit your question to include that code.

Comment: Alright I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a lambda in your `Where()`, you can also just use `StartsWith()` instead of `Contains()` if you want to be more specific:

```
var list = _context.CORP_MatrixPositionOLDWay
               .Where(x => x.ParentOrgLevel.StartsWith("0001"))
               .Select(x => x.ChildLAN);
```

**Given your latest edit**

Your view expects a model of `IEnumerable<Certifications.Models.CORP_MatrixPositionOLDWay>`

Your action must return a View with that type as a model:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var ParentORG = _context.CORP_MatrixPositionOLDWay
             .Where(i => i.ParentLAN == UserInformation.Globals.LANID);

    return View(ParentORG);
}
```

If you want your view to have only the `ChildLAN` properties (as you indicated in your comment below) then you'll have to adjust your view's model to be of type IEnumerable.  However keep in mind that by doing this you will lose all the other functionality of your view (since its dependent on other properties of the `CORP_MatrixPositionOLDWay` class.  What you likely want to do is create a new class called `IndexViewModel` or something like that.  and have it contain both things you need:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    //Name these properties better than I have  

    public IEnumerable<string> ChildLans {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<CORP_MatrixPositionOLDWay> DataList {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: it says 'char' does not contain a definition for 'ParentOrgLevel' and no extension method could be found

Comment: That almost did the job. I want it just to grab the ChildLans and not all of the records.

Comment: It gave me this error when i ran it......            InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Certifications.Models.CORP_MatrixPositionOLDWay]'.

Comment: That error happened on executing the code I posted?  It sounds like you tried using `list` somewhere else....

Comment: I changed the variable and I am still getting the same error

Comment: You copied my code 100% and its throwing an exception?

Comment: Yes. It has to do with the .Select statement. When I remove the whole select statement the code runs fine.

Comment: The Select statement is 100% fine given the model code you posted in your question.  Are you declaring the variable as `var list` and not explicitly typed?

Comment: yes. I even changed the variable list to something different and im still getting the error.

Comment: Without seeing more of your code there isnt more I can do.  With the code you provided, my answer should be 100% right.

Comment: I think it has to do with my index view that I scaffolded. I added my index view to the code as well

Comment: Your view expects a model of IEnumerable<CORP_MatrixPositionOLDWay>. You cannot send a IEnumerable<string> to your view